# How to proceed to next step when if statement is true for more than xy amount of seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tried to find an answer, didn't have luck.
How to proceed to next step when if statement is true for more than xy amount of seconds.

Example:

```
if 10 > 5 and True for 5 seconds:
    print("you did it")
```

This is what I meant. Modified Rakesh's script a little bit to help newbies like me:

```
import time
import random

while True:
    blue = random.random()
    red = random.random()
    print("orange")
    print("green")
    if blue < red:  # check condition
        time.sleep(5)  # sleep 5 seconds
        if blue < red:  # check condition again
            print("you did it")  # if condition still true after 5 seconds print message
            break    # break while loop and continue with script
    else:
        continue   # if condition is not true continue with loop until condition is true

print("purple")
print("yellow")
```

Comment: What? can you explain it ?

Comment: I don't understand. 10 > 5 is always true.

Comment: ...except for large values of 5

Comment: Does it need to be continuously true, or just true at two points in time that are 5 seconds apart? (That is, does the clock reset if the expression goes false before the 5 seconds are up?)

Comment: Thanks for help guy, edited original post to show you what I meant and help newbies for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **time module.**

**Ex:**

```
import time
if (condition_if_True):
    time.sleep(5)   #Sleep 5 sec
    if (condition_if_Still_True):   #Check condition again
        print("you did it")
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops can have an `else` clause which is run if a `break` is not executed. You could get the current time and write a `while` loop that exits on timeout. If the condition is met early, do a break. Now you know that the `else` is the timeout.

```
import time
something = 10
end = time.time() + 5
while time.time() < end:
    do_something()
    if something < 5:
        print("exit early")
        break
else:
    print("you did it")
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `break` in the `while`?

Comment: @Jeronimo yes, thanks!

Comment: @tdelaney Both yours and Rakesh scripts did the job. That is exactly what I meant. Used little bit of both scripts and added it to original post to show newbies for future reference. Thanks mate!